# How do you convert contents of a text field to a date format using php?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have been trying to convert the contents of a text field into a date format before saving it into my database but everything I try seems to fail. Example of a date entered by the user would look like "24/02/2014" (dd/mm/yyyy)

Code from form:

```
<td>Date of Test:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Date1" id="dot2"/></td>
```

Code from form action page:

```
$dateoftest = strtotime($_POST['Date1']);
$newdate = date('Y-m-d', $dateoftest);

$sql="INSERT INTO `tableOne`(`DateofTest`) VALUES ('$newdate')";
```

The segment of the code is all the code that is relevant to the problem. The database field is of type "date". The code doesn't store the entered values but instead 0000-00-00.

Comment: can you please echo $newdate value and paste it here as you code looks fine.

Comment: I tested it out posting the data to a new page and the date appears perfectly fine! e.g "25/02/1992" appears as 1992-02-25 to the posted page. There must be a conflict with the php that I am not seeing in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your date format is wrong, according to php.net `strtotime` works with:

*Note*:

> Dates in the `m/d/y` or `d-m-y` formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (`/`), then the American `m/d/y` is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (`-`) or a dot (`.`), then the European `d-m-y` format is assumed.
>   To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use `ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)` dates or `DateTime::createFromFormat()` when possible.*